# why many small memcpy is faster than one large memcpy?

Tags: c++, memory, memcpy

I found that having many small memcpy is faster than having a one large memcpy. I can't understand why it would be the case. Isn't memcpy better at copying a big block of data?

I've tested the following code on both  VC++ 2017 and Intel compiler 2018.

time for one large memcpy: 0.457913 and time for many small memcpy: 0.121063

```
typedef double tp;
size_t sz = 100;
size_t nm = 1000000;
tp* x = new tp[sz*nm];
std::vector<tp*> y(nm);
for (int i = 0; i < nm; ++i)
   y[i] = new tp[sz];

tp*  z1 = new tp[sz*nm];
std::vector<tp*> z2(nm);
for (int i = 0; i < nm; ++i)
   z2[i] = new tp[sz];

double currTime, lastTime;

lastTime = omp_get_wtime();
memcpy((void*)z1, (void*)x, sizeof(tp)*sz*nm);
currTime = omp_get_wtime();
std::cout << "time for one large memcpy: " << currTime - lastTime << std::endl;

lastTime = omp_get_wtime();
for (int i = 0; i < nm; ++i)
    memcpy((void*)z2[i], (void*)y[i], sizeof(tp)*sz);
currTime = omp_get_wtime();
std::cout << "time for many small memcpy: " << currTime - lastTime << std::endl;

delete[] x;
delete[] z1;
for (int i = 0; i < nm; ++i)
{
   delete[] y[i];
   delete[] z2[i];
}
```

Comment: Probably better to use `std::vector<std::vector<tp>>`to avoid all those pointers and *news* and *deletes*.

Comment: What optimizations are used? I got different results, 0.52 sec for one large memcpy and 0.68 sec for many small memcpy. Try to change test order.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce (different compiler though)](http://quick-bench.com/sqHAY1lUCmRPjmfxm8ie9frWG-4). There are probably several unwise profiling choices at play in your example: Only one run, no warmup, etc., so I would be hesitant to draw conclusions from your test. In particular, whatever you see in this microbenchmark might be very different in practice (caching, paging, memory/allocation layout...).

Comment: I tried with VS and I see the same thing. Very puzzling. In debug the results are as one would expect, but selecting the release build produces this result.

Comment: Same thing happens [here](http://rextester.com/UJJRS76336).